# Duplicate IPN on profile cancel

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm having an issue where Paypal sends a duplicate 'recurring_payment_profile_cancel' type IPN when a user cancels a subscription. If I initiate the cancellation via Express checkout NVP I only get one IPN, but if the user cancels from his Paypal account dashboard I get two near identical messages, both get a 200 response code and no retries so it doesn't look like a problem on my end.

This happens to me both on Sandbox and Live environments.

Is this normal? a bug? or something I could avoid?

Comment: You can get a duplicate IPN of any type at any time. You have to code defensively against it in all cases. All the sample IPN code does so.

Comment: have filed a ticket with MTS? Do file a ticket and they will help you check that

Comment: I've only checked the php sample which details validating the IPN, but as you say if this is a common thing I will have to accommodate ignoring the additional ones I get. I did file a ticket, it's been a week unfortunately with no response.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal mts confirmed this was a bug and rolled out a fix, this has been fortunately solved.

Thanks.